# Lazy construction - virtual method vs. if-then to stub a getter

Tags: c++, performance, inheritance, data-structures, lazy-loading

The background to my problem is that I'm trying to create a lazy grid structure, where areas of the grid are only instantiated when required, otherwise they return a default value when queried.

Boiling down the problem a little, consider the following mockup of my situation:

```
struct Container {
  std::vector<Base> data;

  float get(int indexOuter, int indexInner) {
     return data[indexOuter].get(indexInner);
  }
}
```

I want to stub the `Base::get` function in some cases to always return the same value, whereas in other cases I want to return the value in some array.  I imagine two possible solutions.

The first solution is to use a flag on `Base`, i.e.

```
struct Base {
  std::vector<float> data;

  float get(int indexInner) {
    if (data.empty()) return 0;
    return data[indexInner];
  }
}
```

This solution would involve destroying `data` (resize to zero) when the object enters "stub mode", and recreating `data` when the object is once again concrete.

The second solution I can think of is inheritance, i.e.

```
struct Container {
  std::vector<Base*> data;

  float get(int indexOuter, int indexInner) {
     return data[indexOuter]->get(indexInner);
  }
}
struct Base {
  virtual float get(int indexInner) = 0;
}
struct Stub : public Base {
  float get(int indexInner) {
    return 0;
  }   
}
struct Concrete : public Base {
  std::vector<float> data;

  float get(int indexInner) {
    return data[indexInner];
  }   
}
```

and then replace instances of `Concrete` with instances of `Stub`, and vice versa, in the `Container`'s `data` array when necessary (taking care to ensure clean destruction).

The question is one of performance.  `Container::get` will be called 1000s of times a second, maybe more.  However, `Base`s entering/exiting "stub mode" will occur far less frequently.

With the two solutions proposed above, the first solution involves an additional if-then clause, whereas the second solution involves an indirection from the `Base` pointer to the object, plus an indirection from the abstract method to the derived implementation.

Which of these solutions would give the best performance?  Are there any other more-performant solutions I have not considered?

Comment: _"Which of these solutions would give the best performance"_ - Why not measure their CPU usage with a profiler and find out?

Comment: FYI, these are usually called "sparse" data structures, which may help you search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern processors do not like conditional code, particularly if it's not "predictable" (in other words, your data is sometimes filled in, and sometimes not.

Jumping through the pointer to a function is generally faster than a conditional branch (considering you also need to check whether it is stubbed or not [Although you could use `data.empty()` which would be simple to check for the compiler]).

So, without benchmarking the two solutions, my guess is that the virtual `Stub` and `Concrete` will be faster. However, it will depend a bit on the use-cases.

The `Stub` implementation will also take up a little less data. On the other hand, if this is the ONLY reason for using a pointer in the `std::vector<Base*> data;`, then you may want to consider using the `isStubbed` (or `data.empty()`) and using `std::vector<Base>` instead - saving a level of indirection overall - which CAN be better, depending on circumstances.

Ultimately, if it's important for performance, you'll want to implement both, run benchmarks with varying load-patterns, and measure the time. Also look at the profiling data for each of the runs to understand where the code is spending time.

Comment: A very good point you make there, regarding `std::vector<Base>`  avoiding the (additional) indirection of a `std::vector<Base*>`.  In effect, this means the conditional solution can avoid two levels of indirection.  Is two levels of indirection more costly than a single conditional, though?

Comment: Now, that, as they say, is the "million dollar question". If I could answer that, accurately, for every case, I'd probably also be able to tell what the weather will be on Wednesday accurately, or what the IBM share value will be at the end of the month, etc. So much of these things will depend on exactly how the compiler generates code, what the particular processor likes & dislikes, cache usage patterns, butterfly wings flapping on the South Pacific, and what floor the elevator is on right now.

Comment: LOL.  Well I've updated the question with your suggestions, and will accept your answer if noone else knows.  Indeed it looks like a little profiling investigation may be the only answer - and, as you say, even that may only be valid for my platform and current compiler version etc.